# What is the best way to simplify z-index change on hover in jquery between multiple divs?

Tags: jquery, z-index

Pretty new to jQuery. Is it possible to turn these functions into one? Or is there any way to simplify this process? I don't feel like this is a good approach on things.

Basically what i am looking for is when a button is hovered, the z-index value of a div changes to a higher position from the last one displayed.

```
$(".cube").hover(function(){
  $(".backgroundred, .backgroundorange").css("z-index", "-1");
     $(".backgroundblue").css("z-index", "9");
 });

 $(".cube2").hover(function(){
   $(".backgroundblue, .backgroundorange").css("z-index", "-1");
     $(".backgroundred").css("z-index", "10");
 });

$(".cube3").hover(function(){
   $(".backgroundblue, .backgroundred").css("z-index", "-1");
     $(".backgroundorange").css("z-index", "12");
 });
```

See fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/dfjf3kyr/1

Thank you a lot in advance.